# How can I change the columns and rows as needed by just entering the numbers I want?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

First of all, I am a newbie to programming. And I was commissioned by my friend to fix his code.
Where it is written in react and javascript.
which is a picture hexagonal grid
As I have read and found that every time I go to edit The height and width denominators of the hexagonal grid change according to its height and size. Which is what my friend wants. I want it to be able to create columns and rows by inputting numbers.
I tried to fix it at the point of calculation.
But I don't understand that.
How to fix it?

---

```
 const getGridDimensions = (gridWidth, gridHeight, N) => {
   const a = (5 * gridHeight) / (gridWidth * Math.sqrt(2));
   const b = gridHeight / (2 * gridWidth) - 2;

   const columns = Math.ceil((-b + Math.sqrt(b * b + 4 * N * a)) / (2 * a));

   const hexSize = Math.floor(gridWidth / (3 * columns + 0.5));
   const rows = Math.ceil(N / columns);

   return {
    columns,
    hexSize,
    hexWidth: hexSize * 2,
     hexHeight: Math.ceil(hexSize * Math.sqrt(3)),
     rows,
  };
 };
const tryInvoke = (func, params = [], defaultValue = null) => {
  return isFunction(func) ? func(...params) : defaultValue;
};

const HexagonGrid = (props) => {
  const {
    hexagons,
    gridHeight,
    gridWidth,
    renderHexagonContent,
    hexProps,
    x,
    y,
  } = props;

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    columns: 1,
    hexSize: 1,
    hexWidth: 1,
    hexHeight: 1,
    rows: 0,
  });

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(hexagons) && gridWidth > 0 && gridHeight > 0) {
      setState((prevState) => {
        const newColumns =
          props.columns ||
          getGridDimensions(gridWidth, gridHeight, hexagons.length).columns;
        const newRows = props.rows || Math.ceil(hexagons.length / newColumns);
        return {
          ...getGridDimensions(
            gridWidth,
            gridHeight,
            hexagons.length,
            newRows,
            newColumns
          ),
        };
      });
    }
  }, [hexagons, gridWidth, gridHeight, props.columns, props.rows]);

  const getHexDimensions = (row, col) => {
    const dimensions = {
      width: `${state.hexWidth}px`,
      height: `${state.hexHeight}px`,
      x: col * state.hexSize * 3,
    };
    if (row % 2 === 1) {
      dimensions.x += state.hexSize * (3 / 2);
    }
    return dimensions;
  };

  const getRowDimensions = (row) => {
    const dimensions = {
      y: `${row * (state.hexSize * (Math.sqrt(3) / 2))}px`,
      height: `${state.hexHeight}px`,
      width: gridWidth,
    };
    if (row % 2 === 0) {
      dimensions.marginLeft = `${(state.hexSize / 2) * 3}px`;
    }
    return dimensions;
  };

  return (
    <svg width={gridWidth} height={gridHeight} x={x} y={y}>
      {times(state.rows, (row) => {
        const remaining = hexagons.length - row * state.columns;
        const columns = remaining < state.columns ? remaining : state.columns;
        const rowDim = getRowDimensions(row);
        return (
          <svg
            key={row}
            width={rowDim.width}
            height={rowDim.height}
            y={rowDim.y}
          >
            {times(columns, (col) => {
              const iHexagon = row * state.columns + col;
              const hexagon = hexagons[iHexagon];
              const hexDim = getHexDimensions(row, col);
              const _hexProps = tryInvoke(hexProps, [hexagon], hexProps);
              return (
                <svg
                  key={iHexagon}
                  height={hexDim.height}
                  width={hexDim.width}
                  x={`${hexDim.x}px`}
                >
                  <Hexagon {..._hexProps} flatTop>
                    {tryInvoke(renderHexagonContent, [hexagon], <tspan />)}
                  </Hexagon>
                </svg>
              );
            })}
          </svg>
        );
      })}
    </svg>
  );
};
```

I'm very curious to see how this can be fixed.
If you could give me a brief explanation, that would be great.
thank you!